# Express, get url pattern on a request (not the url used by the user)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating a app with complex routes access, so then I'm creating a middleware to check if the user has access to some routes, so far so good.

I get the `req.originalUrl`, get the profiles and check if this profile has access.

My problem is when I have params on the url, for example:

`/api/user/:userId` is transformed on `/api/user/12345`

If I search on my database, I will have `/api/user/:userId`, not the url to ever single user.

How can I get the "original" url Express used on the request?

I tried `req.baseUrl`, `req.url` and `req.originalUrl`

As a test:

```
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.log("req.baseUrl >> ", req.baseUrl + ""); // returns nothing
  console.log("req.url >> ", req.url); // returs /api/user/1
  console.log("req.originalUrl >> ", req.originalUrl); // returs /api/user/1

  next();
});
```

Comment: [`req.route.path`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.route)

Comment: @Ouroborus it give me some light, but it working only on the 'end' or the route.
If I use on a middleware it got a exception because the req.route is undefined

Comment: I'd imagine that's because the middleware happens before dispatching. Since dispatching hasn't happened, the pattern match hasn't been decided yet and so isn't set. (You can `.use` against a path prefix, but I image that doesn't really meet your needs.)

Comment: There is no mount path for the middleware, so the `req.route` is `undefined`.

Comment: I'm thinkg i will need to do a 'especial' validaiton, check the patch with some Regex and change the string if is a match to what i spect find on DB. I don't like that much of this ideia, but at least i could continue until I find a final one